# Find the least positive integer with 24 positive divisors

Tags: divisibility, divisor-counting-function

Find the least positive integer with $24$ positive divisors

If we assume the integer is $=a^x.b^y.....$

And $(x+1)(y+1)......=24$
Then there are too many variables 
How can I get least variables?

Comment: Won't it be just $\Pi_{i=1}^{24}i$?

Comment: Won't it just be $\Pi_{i=1}^{24}1$ as one has not specified uniqueness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$ the number of divisors is $(\alpha_1+1)\cdots(\alpha_k+1)=24$. The best case is to consider the $\alpha_k$s as decreasing when $p_i$s are increasing prime factors so some possible such cases are$$\alpha_1=23\\(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)=(11,1)\\(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)=(7,2)\\(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)=(5,3)\\(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)=(5,1,1)\\(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)=(3,2,1)\\(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4)=(2,1,1,1)$$by a simple investigation the answer is $360$